# Rdma infiniband cannot open hosts (iberror: discovery failed) Port state: Down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, infiniband, rdma

I am facing an issue while configuring rdma and Infiniband on my two nodes. Both of these two nodes are connected and I have installed the recommended software libraries and packages required.
But my port status is down and physical state is Disabled. I tried to enable the state but I get the error of can’t open MAD PORT

> :~# ibportstate -L 1 3 enable

> ibwarn: [6772] mad_rpc_open_port: can't open UMAD port ((null):0)
> ibportstate: iberror: failed: Failed to open '(null)' port '0'

Infiniband ibstatus returns this:

```
Infiniband device ‘mlx5_0’ port 1 status:
default gid: fe80:0000:0000:0000:1270:fdff:fe6e:43e0
base lid: 0x0
sm lid: 0x0
state: 1: DOWN
phys state: 3: Disabled
rate: 100 Gb/sec (4X EDR)
link_layer: Ethernet
```

I don't understand what seems to be the issue here, I also upgraded the firmware but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I am sharing the answers for others to see so the issue was the network interface, you need to see which network interface the Infiniband and check the status.

> root@dtn0:~# /etc/init.d/openibd status

```
 HCA driver loaded

 Configured Mellanox EN devices:
 ens11np0

 Currently active Mellanox devices:


 The following OFED modules are loaded:

 rdma_ucm
 rdma_cm
 ib_ipoib
 mlx5_core
  mlx5_ib
   ib_uverbs
   ib_umad
   ib_cm
   ib_core
   mlxfw
```

After that, I just assigned Ip and netmask on the interface and I was able to use the interface and reach the network.

> root@dtn0:~# ifconfig ens11np0 10.0.0.50/24